# Stacking a bar chart over a table

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to put the bar chart **over**  the table. I cannot do this and don't understand why.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplot}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Year,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=0.7,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,408184) (2011,408348)
         (2010,414870) (2009,412156) (2008,415 838)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,388950) (2011,393007) 
        (2010,398449) (2009,395972) (2008,398866)};
\legend{Men,Women}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
{\sc Dossiers} & {\sc Pages} & {\sc \'Echéances} & {\sc Label}\\
\hline
\hline
Histoire des Sciences (1) & 15p mini & 01/01/17 & A\\
\hline
Histoire des Sciences (2) & 15p mini & 01/01/17 & B\\
\hline
Neurosciences & 10 (2x5) & 01/01/17 & C\\
\hline
Histoire         & 6-10p    & 01/01/17 & D\\
\hline
Histoire des SVT & 10p      & " + 2 sem. & E 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you mean over as in over printing or just higher up the page (in which case you want a blank line between)

Comment: For you source .tex can you use a block with `{ }`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mean higher up. It seems to me that I tried the blank line (or is it some special command  ?)

Comment: no a blank line would be fine, but your example just produces `! LaTeX Error: File \`pgfplot.sty' not found.`

Comment: oh apart from in `standalone` is your real document `standalone` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It compiles as is. Maybe I have this stylesheet somewhere.

Comment: Well it should definitely be `pgfplots`, with an `s` at the end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It works perfectly, thanks (I must now learn the subtleties of varwidth now :)

Comment: check your log file for the path of `pgfplot.sty`  it must be a local file, there is no file of that name in the standard distributions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle [it must be a local file]----> yes it is "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty"

Comment: no that is the standard one `pgfplots.sty` with an `s`  your code above loads `pgfplot.sty` without an `s` (or rather, generates an error that the file does not exist)

Comment: Apparently, there's no pgfplot.sty. The log file is [here] [https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/~duchamp/Tmp/] BTW what is the syntax for the web links in your site ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tikzpicture` and `tabular` have no special spacing rules, they are just positioned like big letters.

you have

```
X
Y
```

which makes

> X Y

and you want

```
X

Y
```

which makes

> X
>
> Y

If using `standalone` class you need

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
```

`varwidth` for any vertical mode constructs.

Answer (score 5):

As an aside, you could also place the `tabular` in a `\node` inside the `tikzpicture`. Further, note that `\sc` is deprecated in favor of `\scshape`, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs} % added for \toprule,\midrule,\bottomrule
\usepackage{array} % added for the *{4}{c} syntax
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Year,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=0.7,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,408184) (2011,408348)
         (2010,414870) (2009,412156) (2008,415 838)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,388950) (2011,393007) 
        (2010,398449) (2009,395972) (2008,398866)};
\legend{Men,Women}
\end{axis}
\node [above] at (current bounding box.north) {%
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
\toprule
\scshape Dossiers & \scshape Pages & \scshape \'Echéances & \scshape Label\\
\midrule
Histoire des Sciences (1) & 15p mini & 01/01/17 & A\\
Histoire des Sciences (2) & 15p mini & 01/01/17 & B\\
Neurosciences & 10 (2x5) & 01/01/17 & C\\
Histoire         & 6--10p    & 01/01/17 & D\\
Histoire des SVT & 10p      & " + 2 sem. & E  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]